# Angular 8 authorization directive only works first time

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-directives

I am making a directive to show functionalities based on the role of the logged-in user.
In the OnInit I subscribe to a BehaviorSubject that emit the current user and save it in a variable:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profileService.currentProfileData$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      )
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.currentUser = user;
        this.updateView();
      });
  }
```

The updateView method is responsible for displaying or not the functionality based on the user's role:

```
private updateView() {
    if (!this.currentUser || !this.currentUser.roles || this.currentUser.roles.length === 0) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      return;
    }

    if (this.authorities.find(a => this.currentUser.roles.includes(a))) {
      if (!this.isVisible) {
        this.isVisible = true;
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      }
    } else {
      this.isVisible = false;
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
```

And I get the roles of the parameters in the directive:

```
@Input()
  set hasAnyRole(value: string | string[]) {
    this.authorities = (typeof value === 'string' ? [<string>value] : <string[]>value);
  }
```

This is my profile service:

```
export class ProfileService implements OnInit {

  private currentProfileData = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as any);
  public readonly currentProfileData$ = this.currentProfileData.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const currentUser = this.storageService.getItem('token') ? this.storageService.getItem('user') as User : {} as any;
    this.currentProfileData = new BehaviorSubject<User>(currentUser);
  }

  changeUserInfo(user: User) {
    // Update user data in storage
    this.storageService.setItem('user', user);
    this.currentProfileData.next(user);
  }
}
```

Once I log in, I give next in the BehaviorSubject(changeUserInfo method) and emit the logged in user.
At that time the directive works and the functionalities of the current user are displayed.
But if I move to another view, or update the current view (F5) the directive gets undefined in the user and stops working.
Shouldn't the BehaviorSubject issue the last value, which in this case is the user logged in?

There is something that I am not doing well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to store `currentUser` into localstorage using LocalStorage. Try to fetch `currentUser` from localstorage `updateView`. if it is there than use it or kick user to Login screen.

Comment: Yes @NimittShah, that is the way. Thanks !

Comment: Dont store it in locaStorage its not safe store it in cookie